# Hibernate Query Language Problem

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

Well, I have implemented a distinct query in hibernate. It returns me result. But, while casting the fields are getting interchanged. So, it generates casting error. What should be the solution?

As an example, I do have database, "ProjectAssignment" that has three fields, aid, pid & userName. I want all distinct userName data from this table. I have applied query :

```
select distinct userName, aid, pid from ProjectAssignment
```

Whereas the ProjectAssignment.java file has the fields in sequence aid, pid & userName. Now, here the userName is first field in output. So, Casting is not getting possible.

Also, query :

```
select aid, pid, distinct userName from ProjectAssignment
```

is not working.

What is the proper query for the same ? Or what else the solution ?

The code is as below :

System Utilization Service Bean Method where I have to retrieve data :

```
public List<ProjectAssignment> getProjectAssignments() {
        projectAssignments = ProjectAssignmentHelper.getAllResources(); //Here comes the error
        return projectAssignments;
    }
```

`ProjectAssignmentHelper` from where I fetch Data :

```
package com.hibernate;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class ProjectAssignmentHelper {

    public static List<ProjectAssignment> getAllResources() {
        List<ProjectAssignment> projectMasters;

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("select distinct aid, pid, userName from ProjectAssignment");
        projectMasters = (List<ProjectAssignment>) query.list();
        session.close();

        return projectMasters;
    }
}
```

Hibernate Data Bean :

```
package com.hibernate;

public class ProjectAssignment  implements java.io.Serializable {

     private short aid;
     private String pid;
     private String userName;

    public ProjectAssignment() {
    }


    public ProjectAssignment(short aid) {
        this.aid = aid;
    }
    public ProjectAssignment(short aid, String pid, String userName) {
       this.aid = aid;
       this.pid = pid;
       this.userName = userName;
    }

    public short getAid() {
        return this.aid;
    }

    public void setAid(short aid) {
        this.aid = aid;
    }
    public String getPid() {
        return this.pid;
    }

    public void setPid(String pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

Error :

For input string: "userName"

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "userName"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:447)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:497)
 at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.toInteger(ArrayELResolver.java:375)
 at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:195)
 at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
 at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
 at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
 at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
 at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:102)
 at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
 at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
 at javax.faces.component.UICommand.getValue(UICommand.java:218)
 at org.primefaces.component.commandlink.CommandLinkRenderer.encodeMarkup(CommandLinkRenderer.java:113)
 at org.primefaces.component.commandlink.CommandLinkRenderer.encodeEnd(CommandLinkRenderer.java:54)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:878)
 at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70)
 at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:54)
 at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTable(DataTableRenderer.java:525)
 at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:407)
 at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:193)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:878)
 at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70)
 at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:54)
 at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeContents(TabViewRenderer.java:198)
 at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:130)
 at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:48)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:878)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1620)
 at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1613)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:380)
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:802)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:664)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:497)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:364)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:314)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:783)
 at org.apache.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspService(welcome_jsp.java from :59)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:406)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:483)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:373)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
 at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
 at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
 at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
 at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
 at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Add the mapping configuration of hibernate (hibernate.cfg.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use HQL?

The idea of Hibernate is to work with entities and not with tables. Ideally, you would load the entities and iterate through them getting the fields you want.

I would suggest you to use Hibernate Criteria and Criterion to that query.

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(ProjectAssignment.class);
List projectAssignments = crit.list();
```

And then iterate through the list getting the fields you want.

Comment: In my experience the Criteria (and DetachedCriteria) don't yet have the full functionality you can get in writing your own HQL statements.  Also, your criteria here doesn't address the distinct constraint.  Finally, HQL still deals with the entities and not the tables since in HQL you query against the entities and their properties, not against tables and columns.

Comment: Thank you very much.

I got the concept of Criteria. But, the still I didin't get the concept of "GenericDAO". I mean to say the Expression Interface & all elxe. So, I started using HQL.

Answer (score 3):

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select distinct aid, pid, userName from ProjectAssignment");
```

Actually, query.list() will return an instance of ArrayList containing Array of Objects as each element. And each element on array contains value for each column.

e.g. query.list().get(0) will return an array of three objects

```
array[0] = value of aid
array[1] = value of pid
array[2] = value of userName
```

so, `List<Object[]>` can not be cast to `List<ProjectAssignment>`

One possible solution is implement [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html)

something like this.........

First tell Hibernate what transformer to use

```
query.setResultTransformer(new ProjectAssignmentTransformer());
```

Now implementation

```
class ProjectAssignmentTransformer implements ResultTransformer {

@Override
public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuples, String[] aliases) {
            Object aid = tuples[0];
            Object pid = tuples[1];
            Object userName = tuples[2];
             /* construct ProjectAssignment instance using appropriate args*/
    return new ProjectAssignment (aid, pid, (String) userName);
}

@Override
public List transformList(List collection) {
    List<ProjectAssignment> assignments = new ArrayList<ProjectAssignment>();
    for(Object o : collection)
    {
        assignments.add((ProjectAssignment)o);  
    }
    return assignments;
}
```

}

After this you will be able to cast to `List<ProjectAssignment>`.

Hope this helps!

-SE

Comment: Meh.  Pascal's answer was more correct.  The casting error had nothing to do with Hibernate.   And the query doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you use projections like in:

```
select distinct aid, pid, userName from ProjectAssignment
```

You will get an `Object[]` as result (or a `List<Object[]>`), not a `List<ProjectAssignment>`. If you want to get strong typed objects as result when using projections, you should use the `select NEW` expression (assuming you provide the proper constructor):

```
select new com.hibernate.ProjectAssignment(...) from ProjectAssignment.
```

Secondly, I don't get what you actually want. From the plain english description, the query would be:

```
select distinct userName from ProjectAssignment
```

But I'm not sure this is what you expect. Maybe if you clarify in plain english what the expected result is I could help further.

Thirdly, the current problem has NOTHING to do with Hibernate nor casting:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "userName"
```

You are just trying to format a string that is not a number as a number.