# How to write left join in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have following as table structure

```
**BPV table** 
  id, vid, bid

**vt table** 
   vid, name, gender

**uv table**
   uvid, vid, cast,...
```

i want to write left join between BPV ,uv based on vid in hibernate (mysql)

bpv  entity have vt as one to one as well as uv have vt with one to one but there is no bpv &uv in realation

Comment: So, what's the query you tried and it doesn't work?

Comment: You could at least paste the query you are currently using...

Comment: `select * from BPV left join uv on BPV.vid = uv.vid` you need something like that?

Comment: i know in mysql how to do in hibernate

Comment: [i reliazed this is the solution(not actually)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892008/hql-left-join-of-un-related-entities)

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate has Criteria API, which is a good way to execute queries in a OO approach. If you have your persistent entities, then you can do this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(BPV.class, "bpv");
criteria.createCriteria("bpv.vt", "vt", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
criteria.createCriteria("vt.uv", "uv", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
// add restrictions
return criteria.list();
```

Comment: criteria never meets above requirement

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate SQL:

```
from BPV where BPV.uv.cast = "your_condition"
```

It requires properly described entities and dependency;

or pure SQL:

```
select * from BPV left join uv on BPV.vid = uv.vid where uv.cast = "your_condition"
```

Comment: you could just do a hibernate native query, you seem to be using sql/hql anyway

Comment: here is no realtion between bpv and uv these are both have commonly with vt table so above query not possible

Comment: bpv  entity have vt as one to one as well as uv have vt with one to one but there is no bpv &uv in realation

Comment: if you described entity with @OneToOne field and FetchType.EAGER, you may simple use HQL "from bpv". It gives you a List<BPV>, and each BPV will have vt field which have uv field. If you want HQL with condition, use "from bpv where bpv.vt.uv.cast=..." just like an objects in Java

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is not posible, there is a Theta Join solution but it only supports inner join, so you have to give up on that approach and do one of the following solutions:

Map the proper relationship:

If this query is a unusual escenario, you dont necesary have to change your actual mapping , you can make a new dto Class with the new mapping, and use that one for this query.

Use native SQL:

This is prettly simple too, use `.createSQLQuery()`, to run the native query and  you can use `.addScalar()` + `.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(someDto.class))` to get a list of your entity.