# Joins in Hibernate : HQL equivalent of given SQL

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, join, hql

I have 2 tables lets say `fi` and `branchMst` :

```
------------------                       ---------------------
|       fi       |                       |    branchMst       |
------------------                        --------------------
|     fi_id      |                       |     branchId       | 
|      uid       |                       |     branchCode     |
|   branch_code  |                       |     branchName     |
------------------                       ----------------------
```

Now in order to get UID and Branch Name of each fi :

**SQL:**

```
select uid,branchName from fi left join branchMst bm 
                             on fi.branch_code=bm.branch_code;
```

It will provide me the desired Records but i want to do the same via Hibernate Associations .

**Some doubts :**

1) branchCode is not primary Key in branchMst , so how to define my one to many association.

2) If i define association on 5 tables and i want data from 2 tables only , will All assocation mappings still applies ?

Answer (score 1):

**Without introducing the association**

```
select uid, branchName from fi, branchMst bm where fi.branch_code = bm.branch_code;

select uid from fi where branch_code not in (select branch_code from branchMst);
```

and then combine the results programmatically.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892008/hql-left-join-of-un-related-entities).

**With the association**

1) You don't need one-to-many association, you need one-to-one. But you will need to change the `fi` table to reference branchId (PK, I assume). Then use:

```
select fi.uid, bm.branchName from Fi fi left join BranchMst bm
```

2) I don't completely understand what you mean, but you can define the associations with as many entities as needed, and you can of course read only what you need in your queries.

**With the association without changing either `fi` or `branchMst`**

You could create a view on `fi` which will provide `branchId` column, and then map `Fi` entity to the view.

**With the association without any changes in the database**

This is not possible. See this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818373/does-the-jpa-specification-allow-references-to-non-primary-key-columns)

Comment: I want to use **Associations** specifically !!

Comment: How your edited answer going to join 2 tables on branch_code ! where have you specified that .

Comment: So, you don't want to change your tables at all? Because I assumed that you will add foreign key column in one of the tables referencing the primary key of the other table as part of defining the association... Sorry, then my solution won't work.

Comment: I've edited my post again, maybe the solution with the view could be interesting for your use case.