# Getting table aliases correctly in Hibernate Interceptor

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I need to add **soft delete** feature for all entities that my application manages. In order to accomplish that I created a base entity class(MappedSuperclass) with **deleted** field as below:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseVersionableEntity {

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    protected Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION", nullable = false)
    protected Long version;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DELETED")
    protected boolean deleted;

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    // equals/hashCode

}
```

By using hibernate's **interceptor** mechanism I configured a **soft delete interceptor** in order to catch all queries that hibernate executes:

```java
public class SoftSelectInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {

        if(sql.startsWith("select")){
            sql = sql.replace("where ","where deleted=0 and ");
        }

        return super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
    }
}
```

I added below interceptor config to **persistence.xml** file

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="com.my.organization.SoftSelectInterceptor"/>
```

*Note that there is a **SoftDeleteInterceptor** as well. Works with the same way.*

When I execute this code hibernate catches select statement calls in **onPeraparedStatement** method but it adds a table alias in front of the table fields. That is if table name is **reportTemplate**, hibernate give this table **reportTemplate0** alias. So my replace statement needs to be like below:

```java
sql = sql.replace("where ","where reportTemplate0.deleted=0 and ");
```

I can parse the sql string and try to infer correct table aliases. However in complex sql statements (when same entity used multiple times) it would be hard to infer.

I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three options:

1. Use [Hibernate Filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html). Major disadvantage: You have to attach the filter for every entity.

   ```
   @Entity
   // The FilterDef can be declared at package level as well:
   @FilterDef(name="alive", defaultCondition="deleted = 0")
   // Turn on the filter for our entity:
   @Filter(name="alive")
   public class MyEntity { ... }
   ```
2. Use a SQL parser (there are enough out there), modify the parsed result and recreate the SQL. Major disadvantage: There are enough not so trivial statements (including subselects) to modify. You have to be sure to add the restriction only to affected tables.
3. Use a service architecture with a base service, where you always use the same methods for loading/finding entities, which builds the correct query. Major disadvantage: You can't use named queries.

Comment: option 1 and 3 are not applicable for our case since I am supposed to provide a generic solution with minimal effect. I am considering option 2. Is there any global configuration parameter to specify the structure of table alieses. Such as use t prefix (like t1, t2) or use alwayse entity class name prefix etc?

Comment: There are no specific configuration parameters for aliasing. Usually it is _Entity Name_ + _a counter_ +  `_` (see `org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.AliasGenerator.createName(String)`), but I can't guarantee that for all generated SQLs. The documentation says _Subclasses of Loader do *not* have to use aliases of this form_

Comment: I accepted your answer since option 1 is always applicable if we disregard the effort. one last question: Hibernate supports Filter annotation in MappedSupperClasses(since version 3.5.0). what if I used only one filter in mapped superclass and and enforce all of the entities in the project inherit this superclass. Are there any disadvantages of this approach?

Comment: You should check if the filter is applied to collections of the entities as well. As far as I know it is possible to set a filter for collections. And I don't know if you _have to_ set it to enforce the filter.

Comment: Filters need to be declared on collections as well. Also, keep in mind that filters take no effect to `ToOne` associations (searching by id). This could be a problem if a non-deletable entity is associated in a `OneToOne` association with a deletable entity and the foreign key column is not nullable. Then change it to be nullable and make sure to break the association when soft deleting the deletable instance (by setting null on the owning side of the association).

Answer (score 0):

You could map the deletable entities to database views which select from the original tables with the filter condition (`deleted = 0`).

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, it's impossible to do it the way you are trying to.

1) There is no way to exactly predict what the aliases will look like, especially with complex queries with multiple joins and subqueries. Even if you analyze the source code, it is not part of the public API and as such is subject to change.

However, if you decide to take that endeavor (analyze the Hibernate source for query parsing and SQL generation), keep in mind that you will probably spend your entire summer doing only that since it is a complex and huge code base and a few very important feature requests (like [left joins for non-associated entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892008/hql-left-join-of-un-related-entities)) are waiting for years for it to be refactored.

2) The queries (and subqueries) without the `where` clause will not exclude deleted rows (since your replacement will find no matches):

```
select c from MyEntity;
```

3) Less likely for *where* combination of letters but still possible, *where* might be part of an identifier or a text constant and your replacement would make the query invalid. Suppose someone adds two fields to a `Trip` entity: `fromWhere` and `toWhere`. Maybe not a good naming example, but you get the point.

You could solve it by replacing only occurrences of the whole `where` word, but then imagine a query like:

```
select ... from ... where aColumn = 'A constant with the where word in it'
```

Comment: I thought about that answer as well - but ignored it as it depends on the database if the entity may be changed through a view. And I can't use schema generation for those views and (more important) for the tables, at least I would need additional conversion.

Comment: As far as I understand, there is no solution without pain. Thanks for the edit @Dragan