# Hibernate Criteria: hibernate left join without association

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I am a Hibernate newbie and i have this below query. It is working as i expected. These two tables are not associated. Is there a way to get the same result by using Criteria API or how can i run this query via Hibernate ? Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT p.title, c.content
  FROM posts p
  LEFT JOIN comments c ON p.id = c.post_id
  WHERE p.status = 'A' AND (p.title iLIKE '%r%' OR c.content iLIKE '%r%');
```

Answer (score 0):

Criteria API needs a [path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720502/hibernate-criteria-joining-table-without-a-mapped-association) between entities, so I'm not sure this join could be done using Criteria API. Better do it with [HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892008/hql-left-join-of-un-related-entities) if you have Hibernate >= 5.1:

```
select p.title, c.content
from org.example.Posts p
left outer join org.example.Comments c
on p.id = c.id
where p.status = 'A' AND (lower(p.title) LIKE '%r%' OR lower(c.content) LIKE '%r%');
```

Still, you could stick to using SQL queries with Hibernate or better still, create association between Posts and Comments.

Comment: Having problems with implementing since i am a newbie. Could you please provide an example for left join ?

Comment: I added an example. 2 notes: it requires latest hibernate and HQL doesn't support case insensitive operator ilike, so one has to explicitly lowercase

Comment: I do not have the latest version and i have to do it with Criteria API. I know it does not make sense since there is no path between entities but i didnt design the db and entities.

Comment: And there is no relations in db as well (that is insane) so i think the example you have provided also does not work for me. I need an example with DetachedCriteria.

Comment: It would be nice. Thanks for your help.

Comment: hey, @Tartar, I tried writing a left join with detached criteria and failed, sorry. Because I'm not sure how I can reference c.content from subselect. So, at the moment I'm not sure if that's possible with Criteria API or not. Perhaps someone could provide a better answer